# bitap algorithm comprehension

Tags: python, algorithm, string-matching

I am working on a personalised string matching algorithm based on observing other such algorithms. The following code is from a script implementing the bitap algorithm and I'm trying to understand the syntax, in the process of making the state-vector/ table that will define the similarity between the "string" and the "haystack".

```
letterPositionInNeedle = 0
for symbol in needle:
  letterPositionInNeedle = letterPositionInNeedle << 1 # what is this line supposed to do?
```

I understand the process of making a table to evaluate similarity but the "<<" symbol is confusing me. Is it supposed to iterate the length of the "letterPositionInNeedle"?

Comment: 10 << 1 = 100 .. its shifting the bit making a two bit into a three bit ( for this example of mine)

Answer (score 1):

```
letterPositionInNeedle = letterPositionInNeedle << 1
```

is bit shifting to the left. Logically that is equal to

```
letterPositionInNeedle = letterPositionInNeedle * 2
```